# How to install all the missing packages in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have downloaded a flutter project from google drive. And when i opened it,  packages are missing. Is there any command like 'npm i' in flutter to install the dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

run `flutter pub get` in the project root directory.

make sure to have a good internet connection, it may take a while if the project has a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Running `flutter pub get` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter pub get` in the project root directory.
Should internet connection.
Be sure in project root directory