# How to recover from "flutter clean"

Tags: flutter, dart

I accidently run "flutter clean" on vscode terminal without knowing what it is. now all my code line is in error. How do I recover from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install all the missing packages in flutter project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049917/how-to-install-all-the-missing-packages-in-flutter-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open VS Code terminal then run

```
flutter pub get
```

Your issue will be solved.